# Rebase without removing old branch

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I have the following situation in Git:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G
       \--H--I
```

I want to rebase the branch, but keep the original branch. So I want this:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G
       \--H--I     \--H'--I'
```

The reason is that it's possible that my rebased branch will break things. If it does too much, and I can't easily fix it, I want to keep working with the old branch.

This is in a situation where the master branch is actually based on another repository and is a long way behind the original repository. I'm trying to get our (H-I) branch back up to the latest version of the original master branch.

Comment: If you want to make copies of commits in git, that's called cherry-picking. Rebasing without removing old commits is cherry-picking, not rebasing, it's like ordering a cheeseburger without cheese :) I know it can technically be done, as others have left answers here, but the process is still cherry-picking.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how branches work in Git. A branch is nothing more than a pointer to a commit.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen isn't that splitting hairs? Isn't rebase a scripted cherry-pick anyway (afaik)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just create a new branch an work on it.

```
git checkout your-old-branch
git checkout -b to-be-rebased
git rebase master
```

and work on `to-be-rebased` until you have something workable.

So `your-old-branch` still points to the same exact commit, unaffected.

---

...and the two first checkout steps can be combined into one (as pointed out by [Johnathon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336399/rebase-without-removing-old-branch/55336422?noredirect=1#comment97398041_55336422)) to avoid an unnecessary check out step :

```
git checkout -b to-be-rebased your-old-branch
```

---

Lastly, to be fair to [Lasse's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336399/rebase-without-removing-old-branch/55336422#comment97397948_55336399), it's true that we could have proceeded with `cherry-pick` to the same effect :

```
git checkout -b new-branch master
git cherry-pick master..your-old-branch
```

Comment: Don't I just have an empty to-be-rebased branch then? I need the commits from the your-old-branch branch. Preferably without cherry-picking them all.

Comment: @Peter No. Since the new branch is created from the tip of your old branch, it has the same exact history (so : commits)

Comment: True. Ah, it's that simple. :)

Comment: Suggestion: Combine the first two steps into `git checkout -b to-be-rebased your-old-branch` to avoid a second check out.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart You're right. I've tried to stay atomical but your way is faster indeed.